# Mouse behaving strangely in my laptop

Tags: mouse, hardware

I have HP Pavilion 15 Laptop. I am using wireless optical HP mouse.

My mouse worked fine before some days, but lately it is behaving strangely. It works fine for around 10 seconds. Then completely stops working for 3-4 Seconds. Then again works fine for some time and the cycle continues. I can't find any solution about this anywhere.